# Android TextView does not expand to match parent

Tags: android, textview, android-layout-weight

I have a viewgroup like this image:

[image]

I want to not show those texts that are empty. For example, assume that I have no tips and promo then just Notes should be visible. When I test my program Notes (displayed with red background) does not expand to fill parent although its width set to match parent.

Any idea would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/llNotesContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/tracking_bg_note"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llNotes"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/tracking_notes"
            android:textColor="@color/tracking_font_address"
            android:textSize="13sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvNotes"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:textColor="@color/tracking_font_note"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:background="@color/red"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/vVerticalSeparator"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@color/tracking_separator"/>

    <!-- Tips and Promos -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llTipsPromos"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llTips"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="8dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tracking_tips"
                android:textColor="@color/tracking_font_address"
                android:textSize="13sp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTips"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/tracking_font_note"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:ellipsize="end"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/vHorizontalSeparator"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/tracking_separator"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llPromos"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="8dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tracking_promo"
                android:textColor="@color/tracking_font_address"
                android:textSize="13sp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvPromos"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/tracking_font_note"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:ellipsize="end"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

In the code I have a method that call once I want to update UI. The method is:

```
private void showHideSeparators()
    {
        boolean notes = false;
        boolean tips = false;
        boolean promos = false;

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(this.tvNotes.getText()))
        {
            notes = true;
        }

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(this.tvTips.getText()))
        {
            tips = true;
        }

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(this.tvPromos.getText()))
        {
            promos = true;
        }

        // We need to consider 8 configurations due to 3 variables
        if (!notes && !tips && !promos)
        {
            this.llNotesContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            return;
        }

        if (!notes && !tips && promos)
        {
            this.llNotesToDriver.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            this.llTips.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            this.vVerticalSeparator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            this.vHorizontalSeparator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            return;
        }

        if (!notes && tips && !promos)
        {
            this.llNotesToDriver.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            this.llPromos.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            this.vVerticalSeparator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            this.vHorizontalSeparator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            return;
        }

        if (!notes && tips && promos)
        {
            this.llNotesToDriver.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            this.vVerticalSeparator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            return;
        }

        if (notes && !tips && !promos)
        {
            this.llTips.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            this.llPromos.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            this.vVerticalSeparator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            this.vHorizontalSeparator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            return;
        }

        if (notes && !tips && promos)
        {
            this.llTips.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            this.vVerticalSeparator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            return;
        }

        if (notes && tips && !promos)
        {
            this.llPromos.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            this.vHorizontalSeparator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            return;
        }

        // this is default situation when all is true
        if (notes && tips && promos)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
```

I even tried to invalidate my textView but nothing has changed. Result is like this when I just have notes.

[image]

Comment: i think you should make the whole layout visibility to gone. i mean the layout with id "llTipsPromos".

Comment: @Blackbelt this is just padding. I just removed it although its look like above image without padding around textViews.

Comment: remove layout_weight in this(llTipsPromos) LinearLayout block. Otherwise it will not take other attribute, takes width as permanent for empty data also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a way to cope with the issue. This is the change:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/llNotesContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/tracking_bg_note"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llNotes"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/tracking_notes"
            android:textColor="@color/tracking_font_address"
            android:textSize="13sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvNotes"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/tracking_font_note"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:background="@color/red"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/vVerticalSeparator"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@color/tracking_separator"/>

    <!-- Tips and Promos -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llTipsPromos"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llTips"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="8dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tracking_tips"
                android:textColor="@color/tracking_font_address"
                android:textSize="13sp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTips"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/tracking_font_note"
                android:textSize="15sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/vHorizontalSeparator"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/tracking_separator"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llPromos"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="8dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tracking_promo"
                android:textColor="@color/tracking_font_address"
                android:textSize="13sp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvPromos"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/tracking_font_note"
                android:textSize="15sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what did you change? please provide details

Answer (score 1):

Your `android:padding="8dp"` is making this.

If you want to have padding just on **top** and **bottom**, use

```
android:paddingBottom="8dp"
android:paddingTop="8dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to remove the tips and promos field entirely when there are no tips and promos, and display the red notes section to match parent.

In which case make the `LinearLayout llTipsPromos`  `gone`. This will fill the parent with the red notes section

Answer (score 0):

Try below code -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/llNotesContainer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/tracking_bg_note">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llNotes"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/llTipsPromos"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/tracking_notes"
        android:textColor="@color/tracking_font_address"
        android:textSize="13sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvNotes"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textColor="@color/tracking_font_note"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:background="@color/red"/>
</LinearLayout>

 <View
    android:id="@+id/vVerticalSeparator"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/llNotes"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@color/tracking_separator"/>

Tips and Promos
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llTipsPromos"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llTips"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/tracking_tips"
            android:textColor="@color/tracking_font_address"
            android:textSize="13sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTips"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/tracking_font_note"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/vHorizontalSeparator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/tracking_separator"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llPromos"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/tracking_promo"
            android:textColor="@color/tracking_font_address"
            android:textSize="13sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvPromos"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/tracking_font_note"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

when you want to show note view on full screen then hide your llTipsPromos LinearLayout.It will sure work for you.

Comment: Thanks. Although I have not found where was my problem but your solution works.

Comment: Sorry unaccepted your answer since after testing found that problem reversed. Note is expanding correctly now but Tips and Promos does not expand :(

Comment: have you find solution to your problem?

Comment: sorry for late reply. Please have a look at my answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/30051113/513413